# cgconfig.conf file is missing

Tags: cgroups

I installed cgroup on my linux (3.19.0+) using the following command:

```
apt-get install cgroup-bin
```

However I can't find the file /etc/cgconfig.conf. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/cgconfig.conf` contains information about *your* control groups. There isn't any useful default content. So the package doesn't come with a configuration file in `/etc`.

You seem to be using a Debian-based distribution. There is a sample configuration file in `/usr/share/doc/cgroup-tools/examples/cgconfig.conf` (containing only comments with examples).

You can find this out by knowing that the standard location for example files on Debian is `/usr/share/doc/package-name/examples/`. You can also find this out by looking for files named `cgconfig.conf` (`locate cgconfig.conf`, once the index of the search database has been rebuilt since you installed the package; this normally happens every night). You can also find this out by browsing through the files in the package: `dpkg -L cgroup-tools`. The files are actually in the `cgroup-tools` package and not in `cgroup-bin` because `cgroup-bin` is a compatibility package that's only there to facilitate upgrades by depending on `cgroup-tools` (this is explained in the description of the package).

Comment: What's the path that cgconfig.conf file has to be stored in order to be read by cgroup service? I created and changed cgconfig.conf and restarted the service, but it doesn't seem to be read by the service.

Comment: @Nargesoo `/etc/cgconfig.conf`. If it isn't working, check the logs. I can't help you further with that because I'm not familiar with libcgroup.